# A question about multiple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

How to compute the multiple integral

$$\int \int...\int_{(D)}  dx_1dx_2...dx_n, \ \ D:-1\le x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n\le1, -1\le x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n\le1.$$

Thanks in advanced for your help!

Comment: Hint: change of variable $u_1=x_1+x_2+...+x_n$, $u_2=x_2$, ..., $u_n=x_n$.

Comment: Sorry,I don't really know ,can you write it down in detail?

Comment: You are right. This is much harder than I thought.

Comment: I would recommend to first look at the case of with dimension two. It's quiet easy to make a sketch of the domain of integration in this case (It's the intersection of the three inequalities above). Getting the volume is then quiet straightforward. Furthermore this is then easily generalizable to abrinbrtary dimensions.

Comment: @tired,could you write in detail?

Answer (score 2):

As @tired mentioned, you could use 2D and 3D to visualize it.

We can think about it as a n-D cube with side length $2$. And this cube is divided into 3 parts by the two planes $x_1+...+x_n=\pm 1$.

Consider the distance from the farthest point $(1,...,1)$ to the plane $x_1+...x_n=1$ (the other side is similar). The distance is $\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}$. The distance from the origin to the plane is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

This gives the idea that we could shift the lower corner point $(-1,..., -1)$ to the origin, and the lower plane will be shifted to $x_1+...x_n=n-1$, since the distance should be $\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}$. This is the plane that intersects with each axis at $n-1$.

This cut-off part can then be calculated as

$$I=\int^{n-1}_0 \int_0^{n-1-x_1} \int_0^{n-1-x_1-x_2}...\int_0^{n-1-x_1-...x_{n-1}}dx_n...dx_1$$

So the original integral is $2^n-2\cdot I=2^n-2\frac{(n-1)^n}{n!}$.

Comment: Nicely done!  (+1) This is the most easy way...!

Comment: But,what if $2\le x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_{n-1}$ ? I think we should discuss in many cases.

Comment: @yan: Since $-1\leq x_1+...x_n\leq 1$ and $-1\leq x_n\leq 1$, isn't it impossible? The region should be confined in a $2\times 2\times ... \times 2$ hypercube, with each dimension's boundary $[-1,1]$.

Comment: But what you use in the computation is $1\leq x_1+...x_n$ ,the cut-off parts from the whole volume .

Comment: @yan: That is also bounded by the upper bound $2$. I will see if I can plot a 3D graph for you.

Comment: If $ n\leq 3$,then we have $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_{n-1} \le 2$.But if $ 3<n$ ,it's not true.In fact,we can let $x_1=x_2=\ldots =x_{n-1}=1$.

Comment: @yan: That won't happen since if they are all $1$, $x_n$ cannot be in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: I didn't say that $x_n=1$, just $x_1,...,x_{n-1}=1$.

Comment: @yan: I meant, if they the others are all $1$, remember $x_1+x_2+...x_n\leq 1$, how can $x_n$ still be in $[-1,1]$?

Comment: But your method is to subtract the cut-off parts from the whole volume, so $x_1+x_2+...x_n\leq 1$ is not true.

Comment: I think I made some mistake in my integral. But my whole volume means the n-D hypercube with side length $2$. So it is still bounded by $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @yan: OK, finally figured it out. I believe it is correct this time.

Comment: Oh, thank you! You are so patient!